# springfox swagger generates incorrect base URL

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

The Springfox swagger UI has the wrong base URL.  I'm not clear where port 19080 is even coming from since there are no services listening on that port.  What setting to do I need to make to get springfox to generate the correct base URL?

**Swagger UI**

- http://dev.example.com/newapi/swagger-ui.html

**Wrong  base URL**

- base URL: dev.example.com:19080/newapi

**Correct Base URL**

- base URL: dev.example.com/newapi

Below are the Springfox versions I am using.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change port number,you will add properties file port number.For Example,

```
server.port=8081
```